# Unicode file conversion via Python 3

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, encryption, unicode

I'm currently working on an encryption/decryption program and it works fine on text files, but I'm having problems getting it to work on binary files. Here's an example of the problem:

Let's say I have a PNG file (file A), and when I open it in notepad it looks like:[image]

When I encrypt and decrypt it I get a file (file B) that looks like:[image]

These two files are actually identical, except that file B has a strange encoding that turns unicode charters like ‰ (the first charcter in file A) into \x89, which is not really what I need. Any newlines found in file A also turn into \r\n in file B...

I tried writing file B several different ways, but I think the problem is the way it is returned as a string like

```
 b'\x89PNG\r\n'b'\x1a...
```

after being decrypted. Is there any way I can turn said string into valid charters as seen in file A?

I'm appending the code that writes the files, it may be necessary...

```
text = ''
textFile = open(textFileName, 'rb')
for textLine in textFile:
    text += str(textLine)
textFile.close()  

ciphertext = text
numPassCounter = 0
for password in passwords:
    ciphertext = fEncode(ciphertext, password, num_passwords[numPassCounter])
    numPassCounter += 1   

os.system("copy /y " + textFileName + " " + ciphertextFileName)
ciphertextFile = open(ciphertextFileName, 'wb')
ciphertextFile.write(bytes(ciphertext.encode()))
ciphertextFile.close()

if bool_chk_output:
    plaintext_r = ''
    plaintext_r_file = open(ciphertextFileName, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    for plaintext_r_line in plaintext_r_file:
        plaintext_r += str(plaintext_r_line)
    plaintext_r_file.close()

    plaintext = plaintext_r
    rNumPassCounter = 0
    for rPassword in rPasswords:
        plaintext = fDecode(plaintext, rPassword, rNumPasswords[rNumPassCounter])
        rNumPassCounter += 1
    os.system("copy /y " + textFileName + " " + plaintextFileName)
    plaintextFile = open(plaintextFileName, 'wb')
    plaintextFile.write(bytes(plaintext.encode()))
    plaintextFile.close()

    if text == plaintext:
        print('Success!')
    else:
        print('Error! Plaintext does not match original text.')
```

To avoid confusion: fEncode() and fDecode() both take 3 arguments: 2 strings and an integer.

Comment: Why are you converting all the binary data you read from `textFile` into a string? That's just wrong.

Comment: fEncode() takes the text to be encrypted as a string...

Comment: Then you have a problem. Either you should read and write the files as strings, or better `fEncode` and `fDecode` should work with byte strings.

Comment: Actually, how do I make something equal to an empty byte string?

Comment: An empty byte string is `b''`.

Comment: I got it, tweeked fEncode() and fDecode() to accept byte strings, works perfectly now! Thank you!

Comment: Side note: the PNG header was designed specifically to catch the kind of errors you get from processing such files as text files. Another side note for passers-by: a self-written encryption/decryption program is fine for learning, but should never be used in any kind of production environment.